# Frobenius monads and groupoids

Tags: ct.category-theory, groupoids, monads, frobenius-algebras

For a while, I was looking for a Frobenius monad on Set.  It doesn't exist [as pointed out here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/245068/a-list-like-frobenius-monad).  I am now looking at the 2-category of groupoids.  Does the 2-category of groupoids admit a Frobenius monad?  Does it have a polynomial form?

Comment: It seems to be the exact same argument that Todd Trimble give in the question you linked will apply to groupoid. At least if you interpret the notion in a 2-categorical sense, though I suspect thing wouldn't be mych different if you interpret things in a stricter sense.