# (Co)Monad extension of Lawvere Theories

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let $\aleph^{op}_{0}$ be a skeleton of the category of finite Sets and all functions between them.

A Lawvere theory consists of a small category, $L$ with (necessarily strict associative) finite products and a strict finite product-preserving identity on objects functor $I: \aleph^{op}_{0} \rightarrow L$.  A map of Lawvere theories $f: L \rightarrow L'$ is a (necessary strict product preserving) functor that commutes with the functors $I$ and $I'$.

We can generate a monad from a Lawvere Theory in the following way:

The Monad $T_L$ may be described by the following colimit:
$$T_LX =  \int^{n \in \aleph_0} L(n,1)\times X^n $$

Can we find a similar definition of a category that is a theory in the same sense of a Lawvere theory, but that generates a (Co)Monad on Set, ie both a monad and comonad?  Is there a way to define the (co)unit and (co)multiplication?

There is a bit of [work in this direction by Behrisch, Kerkhoff,and Power](http://opus.bath.ac.uk/30243/6/2jul12.pdf).

As a concrete example, we have the List Monad, which has a Lawvere theory, that of Monoids.  There is a bimonad that is an extension of the List Monad, namely the "Tails" comonad. [We see it here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/237692/list-is-a-monad-but-is-it-a-comonad-with-these-natural-transformations).  What would be the theory of this bimonad?  Can we phrase it like a Lawvere theory?

Comment: The paper you linked to has Power, not Hyland, among the co-authors.

Comment: Let me know if there is any interest in a bounty for this question.